# Split an List<String> into multiple List<String> with word match

Tags: java, list

I have a List like the following.

```
["A $0; B $0; C $0; D $0",
 "B $5.8M; A $24.8M", 
 "A $9k; B $20k", 
 "A TBD; B TBD",
 "C $36k; est. A $36k",
 "A TBD; B TBD",
 "D TBD; B TBD",
 "D $1.1m; B $3m", 
 "A $3.86m; D $7.08m", 
 "C TBD; B TBD"]
```

Exxpected Output:

```
A = [$0, $24.8M, $9k, TBD, $36k, TBD, $0, $0, $3.86m, 0]  
B = [$0,    $5.8M,$20k, TBD, $0, TBD, TBD, $3m, $0, TBD ]  
C = [$0, $0, $0, $0,    $36k, $0, $0, $0, $0, TBD]  
D = [$0, $0, $0, $0, $0, $0, TBD, $1.1m,    $7.08m, $0 ]
```

I want this to split up into 4 `List<String>`, ie A contains all the values of A and if A not present in the source then 0. Similarly split to B,C and D. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: It is hard to determine where the Strings are in your List, please quote them e.g. `"A $0;", "B $0;"` etc.

Comment: i can split it. But the problem is, in each text there may be value A or not. If its not present, i want it as 0. So if i split, i wont get that 0!!

Comment: before splitting test to see if starts with `A` - sorry you do not explain well what you are trying to do.  Sort out you logic first

Comment: What is your expected output? You've shown sample input, but no sample output, and no attempt at code, so it's very difficult to understand what you expect us to contribute, especially since you already seem to know how to `split()` a string.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I agree with your comment

Comment: How should this `est. A $36k` be handled? Is it an A?

Comment: @Andreas: I have added the expected output

Comment: @Henry: Those kind of texts are available in the input format. I need to consider them as A. Because it says as estimated $ value. But i can ignore them and show only values between A and ";" because that will fetch me the $ value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question really leaves a fair amount up in the air as to what is really required but as I understand it through reading the comments...

You have 4 Items within your List (A, B, C, and D). You want to create a List pertaining to each particular Item. If there are 10 data elements within your Main Data List then each Item List (A to D) should ultimately end up with 10 value elements as well. This would be because if a particular Item is not contained within a Main Data Element (like "A" or "B" or "C" or "D" for example) then a value of "$0" is added to that particular Item List anyways. This will always ensure that each list always contains the same number of elements.

Real quick off hand I'd say creating a boolean flag for each Item would be the easiest. Initially set all four flags to false at the start within the Main Data List iteration. As each Main Data Element is parsed (split) and a particular Item Value is added to its specific List, set its flag to true. At the end of the iteration block check which flags are still false. If any then add "$0" to its related List. Upon the next Main Data List iteration the whole process is done again and continues until all Main Data List elements have been processed.

It might look something like this:

```
// Main Data List 
List<String> mainDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    mainDataList.add("A $0; B $0; C $0; D $0");
    mainDataList.add("B $5.8M; A $24.8M");
    mainDataList.add("A $9k; B $20k");
    mainDataList.add("A TBD; B TBD");
    mainDataList.add("C $36k; est. A $36k");
    mainDataList.add("A TBD; B TBD");
    mainDataList.add("D TBD; B TBD");
    mainDataList.add("D $1.1m; B $3m");
    mainDataList.add("A $3.86m; D $7.08m");
    mainDataList.add("C TBD; B TBD");

// Declare Lists for each Item (A to D) Value
List<String> itemListA = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> itemListB = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> itemListC = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> itemListD = new ArrayList<>();
boolean aHit, bHit, cHit, dHit;  // Flags

for (int i = 0; i < mainDataList.size(); i++) {
    aHit = false; bHit = false; 
    cHit = false; dHit = false;
    // RegEx "\\s+" is used below. It means one or more spaces.
    // Split the current Main Data List element string
    String[] tmpString = mainDataList.get(i).trim().split(";\\s+");
    // Iterate through the created array from the Main Data List element split.
    for (int j = 0; j < tmpString.length; j++) {
        // Split each Item element to Item and Value
        String[] data = tmpString[j].replaceAll("est.\\s+", "").split("\\s+");
        // Is it Item A
        if (data[0].equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
            itemListA.add(data[1]);
            aHit = true;
        }
        // Is it Item B
        else if (data[0].equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
            itemListB.add(data[1]);
            bHit = true;
        }
        // Is it Item C
        else if (data[0].equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
            itemListC.add(data[1]);
            cHit = true;
        }
        // Is it Item D
        else if (data[0].equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
            itemListD.add(data[1]);
            dHit = true;
        }
    }
    // Were all items hit in this current iteration
    // of the Main Data List.
    if (!aHit) { itemListA.add("$0"); }     // If no A in line add 0 to A list
    if (!bHit) { itemListB.add("$0"); }     // If no B in line add 0 to B list
    if (!cHit) { itemListC.add("$0"); }     // If no C in line add 0 to C list
    if (!dHit) { itemListD.add("$0"); }     // If no D in line add 0 to D list
}

// Display the Lists in Console....
// Since all Lists will be the same size we
// can use one loop.
System.out.println("\nList A\t\tList B\t\tList C\t\tList D");
System.out.println("======\t\t======\t\t======\t\t======");
for (int i = 0; i < itemListA.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(itemListA.get(i)+"\t\t" + itemListB.get(i)+"\t\t" + 
            itemListC.get(i)+"\t\t" + itemListD.get(i));
    System.out.println("");
}
```

The output should look like:

```
List A      List B      List C      List D
======      ======      ======      ======
$0          $0          $0          $0
$24.8M      $5.8M       $0          $0
$9k         $20k        $0          $0
TBD         TBD         $0          $0
$36k        $0          $36k        $0
TBD         TBD         $0          $0
$0          TBD         $0          TBD
$0          $3m         $0          $1.1m
$3.86m      $0          $0          $7.08m
$0          TBD         TBD         $0
```